# folium program TypeError: a float is required

Tags: folium

I would like how I can make a code that graphs  in folium the coordinates that I give it with  input and linked with polyline

this is what I have done so far:

```
S= input("Indicate the Departure Airport")
L= input("Indicates Arrival Airport ")

aeros = folium.Map (location= [51, 12], zoom_start=2, tiles='Mapbox Control Room')

coord = S,L

folium.Marker([("coord")], popup='Berlin Salida',icon=folium.Icon(icon='send', color='lightblue')).add_to(aeros)

folium.Marker([("coord")], popup='Argentina Llegada',icon=folium.Icon(icon='send', color='lightblue')).add_to(aeros)
aeros
```